# Integrate R with Django

Tags: r, django

I have an R file which contains the following code:

`x<- 4
print(x)`

I want to return this value of x in my localhost using Django. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Look into [plumber](https://github.com/trestletech/plumber). That package can be used to create a rest-api for an R package.

Comment: You may also want to look at [rpy2](http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So to use this api as output to a submit button, what should I do?